# Variables assigned in first SELECT are not retrieved in second SELECT

Tags: sql-server

A mix of non-null/null values are returned for `Start_Index` and `End_index` when executing the following statement:

```
SELECT 
    CHARINDEX('_',  dbo.Components.Cast, 1) AS Start_Index,
    CHARINDEX('_', dbo.Components.Cast, CHARINDEX('_', dbo.Components.Cast, 1) + 1) AS End_Index
FROM dbo.Components
```

As I wish to perform assignment and data-retrieval at the same time, I've separated the `SELECT` statement into two parts. However, `Start_Index` and `End_index` now return `NULL` for all rows:

```
DECLARE @start_index INT
DECLARE @end_index INT

SELECT 
    @start_index = CHARINDEX('_',  dbo.Components.Cast, 1),
    @end_index = CHARINDEX('_', dbo.Components.Cast, CHARINDEX('_', dbo.Components.Cast, 1) + 1)
FROM dbo.Components

SELECT
    @start_index AS Start_Index,
    @end_index AS End_Index
FROM dbo.Components
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `@start_index` and `@end_index` does not belong to `dbo.Components`. remove the `FROM` in the second `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Do they return non-NULL values for *every row*? You have scalar variables. If you write `SELECT @sv = something` and the result set contains *more than one row*, it's not well defined *which value will be the last value assigned to the variable*.

Comment: @ZoharPeled removing the second `FROM dbo.components` and executing returns one row with `NULL` values.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no, I should have stated that - I updated the question. Most of the values are populated with the occasional `NULL`.

Comment: Why not just tell us what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: keep in mind that a variable can hold only one value, so if the Components table has multiple records, the variables will hold A value from the table, you just don't know which one. limit your select to return just one row, and the variable will be populated with what you intend.

Comment: Seconding that this probably doesn't do what you want;  what do you expect from selecting multiple rows into variables that just hold one value?   I think you need to talk more about what it is you want, and how it is different from what you're getting.